# Haskell - Does referencing a list defined using where, create the list just once, or every time the is referenced?

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I can't post the my function that is giving me bother, but basically, I'm having run time problems in my implementation of an A* Search using a heuristic which applies the ceiling function onto the straight line distance between two points. Throughout the function I refer to a list I define at the end using "where", and I believe it is a function within this list causing the runtime problems (as when I remove it, it runs quickly), but I don't understand why because it isn't a complicated function at all. This leads me to believe that the function may be trying to recreate the list every time it is referenced, instead of just once and using the already formed list each time which may be slowing it down, and causing runtimes to increase exponentionally.

i.e. As a basic example, I have referenced "myList" 3 times in the function.

```
function :: Int -> [Int]
function x = head (myList) : (maximum (myList) : minimum (myList))
           where myList = [snd pair | pair <- (zip [0..] [sortBy compare [5*x,3-x,99*x]])]
```

Does this take the same computational time as...

```
function 5 = head ([snd pair | pair <- (zip [0..] [sortBy compare [5*5,3-5,99*5]])]) 
             : (maximum ([snd pair | pair <- (zip [0..] [sortBy compare [5*5,3-5,99*5]])]) 
             : minimum ([snd pair | pair <- (zip [0..] [sortBy compare [5*5,3-5,99*5]])]))
```

i.e. it forms the list from scratch three times throughout the function, even though the result would always be the same.

Or does it calculate it once, and use that value whenever the function is called?

I don't know quite what it would look like otherwise, but as a bit of a muddle of pseudocode and Haskell, I imagine it would go something like this.

```
function 5...
-- First step, Calculate myList
MyList = [snd pair | pair <- (zip [0..] [sortBy compare [5*5,3-5,99*5]])]
       = [-2,25,495]

--Second step, calculate function using myList = [-2,25,495]
function 5 = head (myList) : (maximum (myList) : minimum (myList))
           = head [-2,25,495] : maximum [-2,25,495] : minimum [-2,25,495]
           = -2 : (495 : -2)
           = [-2,495,-2]
```

I hope it's not too difficult to understand what I am trying to ask here.

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Haskell report does not say how it is evaluated: it merely specifies what the result is.

However, GHC will calculate such list only once. This can have a positive effect on peformance if the list is expensive to produce, since it will be produced only once. Mind that, in some cases, it can also have a *negative* effect on performance: for instance, (silly example)

```
let bigList = [1..1000000]
in  foldl' (+) 0 bigList + foldl' (-) 0 bigList
```

will keep the large list in memory until both folds are computed. Instead,

```
foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000] + foldl' (-) 0 [1..1000000]
```

can run in constant space, since the list elements can be garbage collected as soon as they are produced.

For instance, using a 50M list, the first makes GHCi spike to 2.5GB resident memory, and then to return to 100MB. The second has no noticeable effect.